# magento2 FilterableAttributeListInterface issue

Tags: magento2

Could any1 please tell how this error can be solved?

I just have:

**\Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $tglssearchHelper;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('catalogsearch.leftnav');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**My etc di:**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php
>   on line 73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is example in Magento code of how to implements the filterable attribute list.

Basicaly it is a virtual type. In our ElasticSuite module we have this kind of things into the etc/frontend/di.xml :

```
    <virtualType name="searchFilterList" type="Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Search\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
                <item name="boolean" xsi:type="string">Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Boolean</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Then it can be injected into the leftnav block :

```
<virtualType name="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Search" type="Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Block\Navigation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterList" xsi:type="object">searchFilterList</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Maybe you will also have to fix some layout stuffs.

In my memory you have such an example in the Magento_CatalogSearch module.

You can also read the whole code in our ElasticSuite module : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/tree/master/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog

Comment: Thanks Aurelien Foucret, I added FilterableAttributeListInterface preference for FilterableAttributeList type, its working...

Comment: @Sushivam what do you mean with `FilterableAttributeListInterface` preference for `FilterableAttributeList`? Like this? `<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList" />`