# setCurrentCategory producing error when use it for get FilterableAttributeList in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

setCurrentCategory producing below an error when uses it for getting FilterableAttributeList in a custom module via **API**.

```
$this->_layerResolver->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
```

Error:

```
{
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "id",
    "fieldValue": "0"
  },
  "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/emc3/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php(141): Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', '0')\n#1
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125503/69 be sure your attribute is search-able & you've defined the parameters in `di.xml`

Comment: sorry, I could not get your point. Can you please explain bit briefly.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately appears to be a bug in Magento, one of which had been puzzling me for a while! The error is appearing because within `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::setCurrentCategory`, it expects a category to have already been set:

```php
public function setCurrentCategory($category)
{
    if (is_numeric($category)) {
        try {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please correct the category.'), $e);
        }
    } elseif ($category instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
        if (!$category->getId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please correct the category.'));
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Must be category model instance or its id.')
        );
    }

    if ($category->getId() != $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setData('current_category', $category);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

If you follow the code down, the final `if` statement checks if the passed-in category's ID matches that of the current one, but in some environments (such as an API call in Swagger), none have been set, and so `$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()` is invalid, which throws an exception, thus never actually setting the current category; this eventually results in the ID being set to 0, which is what you're seeing.

To fix this, a patch or an override to first check if `$this->getCurrentCategory()` is set would need to be performed. Alternatively, you can do what I've done and set the `current_category` directly:

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
) {
    $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}
```

```php
// $this->_layerResolver->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
// Replace your line above with the below:
$this->_layerResolver->setData("current_category", $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId));
```

This will avoid calling that `setCurrentCategory` method, and applying the category directly. Notice that you have to pass in the full category object instead of just the ID.

I hope this helps!